# System.Net.WebClient is giving me an error while downloading a file from IIS hosted .NET Core 2.1 application

Tags: c#, wpf, webclient

I have a file **"20181023151311-book + notes.txt"** stored in an application hosted in IIS server inside a folder named as **"MyFiles"** and I have to pull the file in a WPF application. I am using **WebClient** to download the file from the server but it is giving me an error

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I tried to use `System.Web.HttpUtitility.UrlEncode` but still I am getting an error. Here is the code I used to pull the file from the server. The code runs perfectly if there are no special characters. Could you please help to solve the issue? Thanks!

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WebClientDownloadDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DownloadFile(@"https://localhost:40120/MyFiles/20181023151311-book + notes.txt");
        }

        public void DownloadFile(string fileUrl)
        {
            using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                var fileName = fileUrl.Substring(fileUrl.LastIndexOf(@"/") + 1);
                client.DownloadFile(fileUrl, System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\Username\\Downloads", fileName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uri encode the special characters then ;) https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Feb/05/Html-and-Uri-String-Encoding-without-SystemWeb

Comment: What do you get if you just put your url in a web-browser? Try replacing the space and + characters with the URLEncoded equivalent values.

Comment: @Peregrine I get an error as HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

Comment: If the system can't cope with `https://localhost:40120/Documents/20181023151311%2dbook%20%2b%20notes.txt` then the only solution is to rename the file to remove those characters

Comment: @Peregrine The system can't code with the Url. Yes, you are right and I should remove those characters before storing to the server when users upload the files. :)

Comment: You say the file is in a folder called "MyFiles" but you are downloading from "Documents" do you have a virtual directory setup to map Documents to MyFiles?

Comment: Download the file from a web browser to make sure you have the right url

Comment: @RichardHubley That's my mistake. I have changes Documents to MyFiles. I can't download the link and I get an error as I get an error as HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.